# Pluing jQuery TE 1.4.0 travado com muito texto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera estou usando o plugin, jQuery TE 1.4.0 , http://jqueryte.com/.
Por ser muito simples e fácil. Ele me atende 100%.

Porém estou tendo um problema, quando eu coloco um texto muito grande que eu copio do world, o plugin simplesmente trava meu navegador.

Fiz alguns testes aqui, e notei que quando eu colo o mesmo texto no bloco de notas, e removo toda a formação o plugin não trava.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Código:

```js
$('.jqte-test').jqte();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-te/1.4.0/jquery-te.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-te/1.4.0/jquery-te.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<textarea name="obs" class="jqte-test"></textarea>
```

Comment: Creio que não a muito a fazer. Aconteceu comigo isso também.

Comment: acho que e algum caracter na formatação que faz ele travar, pois se pegar o texto e colocar em um bloco de nota, e depois colocar dentro do plugin funciona de boa.